# Multiple attribute in collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I am trying to allow for multiple value selection from a collection in a Rails form. The field is working but does not allow for multiple selections (once an alternative option is selected the previously selected is unselected). I am using Bootstrap CDN, which I don't presume is causing issues, but I may be wrong?

Can you see anything wrong with this code?

```
  <div class="field form-group row">
      <%= f.label :industry_ids, class:"col-sm-3"%>
      <%= f.collection_select(:industry_ids, Industry.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true}, size: Industry.all.length) %>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did the answer below work? If not, what happened when you changed it?

Comment: I changed the code to include an empty hash in place of the multiple options, shifting this hash back one position. This did not have any effect on the outcome. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: `<%= f.collection_select(:industry_ids, Industry.all, :id, :name, {}, :multiple => true, size: Industry.all.length) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is that you're putting `{:multiple => true}` in the wrong options hash. The method signature for `collection_select` looks like this:

```
collection_select(object, method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

`multiple` is an html attribute of the select tag itself (here's a [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)), so you want to pass that to `html_options`, not `options`. Your code looks like this:

```
f.collection_select(:industry_ids, Industry.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true}, size: Industry.all.length)
```

Where `Industry.all` is the `collection`, `:id` is the `value_method`, and `:name` is the `text_method`, which means `{ :multiple => true }` is getting passed to `options`, not `html_options`. Move it to the second hash and you should be fine.